# How to save, read, and delete data from NSUserDefault

Tags: objective-c

I am writing an app that needs to save, read, and delete data. I plan to use NSUserDefault.
But not sure the way using it. Please help me explain.

Let's say I have a library, that has many books, each book has : name, publisher, year of publish, and status. So each time, I choose add: i need to fullfill these data. How can I add many books, that make sure everybook has these data, so that I will be able to display the new book that I just add on the table view.

I need explaination for delete data too. Please help me out. Truly appreciate.

Comment: Delete: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:@"name"]; Now alt click the class NSUserDefaults and replace the remove method with one under the heading "Getting Default Values" or "Setting Default Values". The saving happens automatically at small time intervals, but you can also call synchronize on demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` should not be used to hold a library's worth of books. [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html) is exactly what you want for this. Any meaningful app dealing with this sort of data will benefit from a core data backing store (fetch requests, updates of individual values, flexibility to add or remove fields in later versions, validation of data for completeness, etc).

Answer (score 0):

this looks more like a task for CoreData